# The rule of nesting in sanskrit sandhi

Tags: sanskrit

Is this logic correct as per Sanskrit rule?

```
वित् + जात > विद् + जात > विज् + जात = विज्जात

सत् + चित् > सद् + चित् > सज् + चित् > सच् + चित्  = सच्चित्
```

Therefore विद्जात  / विच्जात  or सद्चित / सज्चित are incorrect.

The question is how is it decided if 3 levels or 4 levels of nesting is necessary?

Comment: I am asking because in case of वित् + वान = विद्वान it does not care to go to the next level. I wonder if there is any rule when to nest 2 or 3 levels.

Comment: There are no levels, there are just rules, and each of them tells you where to stop. »वित् + जात > विद् + जात > विज् + जात = विज्जात« is excessive, वित् + जात = विज्जात is enough to have it correct.